# How to have sigmas within sigmas?

Tags: summation, notation

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + ( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} k + 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} k  
 ... = ans$$

Above is a continuous equation, of which the terms of vary depending on the *n*-value. What I wonder is how to make the monster above into a sigma function itself. I placed the paranthesis around the segment where the pattern properly begins. It alternates between a sigma function, and a 1, only for each alternation, the number subtracted from the *n*-value rises.

All the terms, within AND outside of the paranthesis, number *n* + 1. So, if *n* equals 4, then it would look like this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^4 k + \sum_{k=1}^{4-1} k + ( \sum_{k=1}^{4-1} k + 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{4-2} k) = ans$$

If *n* equals five, then it looks like this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 k + \sum_{k=1}^{5-1} k + ( \sum_{k=1}^{5-1} k + 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{5-2} k+ 1) = ans$$

So, how can I put all of this into a sigma? Sigmas within sigmas is a bit outside of my knowledge at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand exactly where the $1$'s are supposed to go.  Are they inside any of the $\Sigma$'s or not?  Also, I don't understand where the sum is supposed to end.  Why are there $4$ $\Sigma$'s both when $n=4$ and $n=5$?

Comment: @saulspatz The 1s are not within the sigmas. I was afraid that this would be confusing, but I didn't see how to make the 1s more separated from the sigmas. Both the sigmas and the 1s make up the terms, so yeah, there are 4 sigmas in both n = 4 and n =5, but there are 5 terms in the first one, and 6 terms in the second one.

Comment: But the formula shows a $\Sigma$ with upper index $n-3$  Why isn't that present when $n=5$?

Comment: @saulspatz because it never reaches that point. The total amount of terms amount to 6 before it can reach *n-3*. If *n* = 6, then the last sigma would have "6-3" above it.

Comment: Why is that?  Where does the formula indicate that?  Where would it end if $n=11$ ?  If $n=117$?

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, so the formula always begins with $$\sigma_{k=1}^n + \sigma_{k=1}^{n-1}$$. This is kind of a prefix, as it is always there, regardless of what the n value is. Then, we start with the parenthesis, which is where the pattern begins. This pattern **always** begins with a sigma function, and this sigma function is $$\sigma_{k=1}^{n-1}$$. Then, the next term is +1, quite simply. Then, the next term after that is $$\sigma_{k=1}^{n-2}$$. Then, the next term after that is +1 again. Then, the next term is $$\sigma_{k=1}^{n-3}$$. Then, the next term is +1 again, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.  Where does the sequence end?  And please, add clarifications in the question body, not the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz The sequence ends at **either** "+1", **or** some sigma function, depending on the n-value, since the number of terms is equal to "n+1".

Comment: This is still not clear.